# "Gorillas have often been portrayed as a fearful animal"

Tags: grammatical-number

Is the following sentence natural?

> **Gorillas** have often been portrayed as **a fearful animal**, but in truth these shy apes rarely fight over sex, food, or territory.

The subject **Gorillas** is plural, but **a fearful animal** is singular.

Answer (score 18):

First of all note the difference between [fearful & fearsome](http://grammarist.com/usage/fearful-fearsome/)

I suppose you could make the jump from singular to plural without anyone noticing, but I'd do it using the comma as your 'jump-point'...

> The gorilla has often been portrayed as a fearsome animal, but in truth these shy apes rarely fight over sex, food, or territory.

Otherwise use

> ...portrayed as fearsome animals, ...

& stick to the plural right through.

After comments -
Yes fearful *could* also be used - however, if there is any chance of ambiguity don't use it.
A fearful noise, fearful wind, fearful storm - inanimate objects could not be confused as being afraid.

> The field mouse has often been portrayed as a fearful animal...

Really?

Comment: +1 for guessing (as I did) that "fearsome" may have been the intended sense.

Comment: Fearful and fearsome have the same meaning in some contexts (e.g. fearful creature = creature to be feared). See, for example, definition 1 at [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/fearful).

Comment: 'Fearful' can indeed be used to mean both 'frightening' and 'tending to 'fear'.

Comment: @alex_d Even if that definition is recognized by some, "fearsome" seems to be the better choice, as it is less likely to be mistaken for "being afraid". - "Fearful", as of definition 3 at [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/fearsome) can mean "afraid", too. But it is not what I would be thinking of, if I read it anywhere. - I would suggest sticking to the prevalent meaning and never, ever using it for the other, as a service to understanding amongst the peoples. :)

Comment: @alex_d I am a 60-yo native BrE speaker, and I read "fearful animal" as "an animal tending to fear".  (Particularly as David Attenborough has been portraying them as actually that since 1979.)

Answer (score 11):

The plural **gorillas** can be understood as a reference to the species as a whole, hence **a** "fearful" or "fearsome" animal, whatever the intended meaning is.

> Kangaroos have often been portrayed as a pugnacious animal.

There is no obligation to see it as a plural or to see it as a reference to the species. It can be either.

But some would prefer to say

> The kangaroo has often been portrayed as a pugnacious animal.

Comment: It seems that the singular "animal" in such examples means "a kind of animal." But can I apply the same reasoning and say "John sees comics as an interesting book," meaning "an interesting type of book"?

Comment: It is not the singular alone. The article contributes to the meaning.  **A pugnacious animal** refers to an abstraction, an animal with the quality "pugnacious".     *He says comics are a subversive genre.* *Comics have often been portrayed as a subversive genre.*

Comment: Are you implying "a pgunacious / fearsome animal" can be understood as an abstraction, while "an interesting book" cannot?

Comment: There are numerous idiomatic phrases that follow the root structure "[plural] are a [singular]". For example, "Mosquitos are a nuisance." I don't know of a name for that sort of structure, nor can I find a source for what singular nouns are valid in such a structure.

Comment: I am saying that **a pugnacious animal** there refers not to an instance but to a class of animal whose only characteristic is its pugnacity.

Comment: *He says octavos are a convenient book to carry.*

Comment: *He sees octavos as a convenient book to carry.*